# Umbraco install UmbracoExamine

Tags: umbraco

Hi all I am getting this error message on a clean install of the latest version of umbraco

Can anyone advise on why this may be occuring or what needs setting up differently

[image: install issue with umbraco]

Answer (score 0):

I would check file system permissions first (if this is your dev environment then I would give the 'Everyone' account full control) to the folder your website project is in.

Also if you installed via Nuget, did you build the solution?

Those are 2 common reasons for errors on install, if no joy then report back.

Comment: by adding lucene.net to umbraco.web.ui fixed this problem